# Consul dev mode unable to see UI using Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, consul

I started a consul agent in dev mode by using the following inside a VM using Vagrant. The command I used is `consul agent -dev`

I confirmed that the UI is working fine by doing a curl on  8500. `curl http://localhost:8500/ui`

However when I am testing from the host machine using `curl http://172.28.128.3:8500/ui` I get the following error.

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.28.128.3 port 8500: Connection refused`

What could be the error. Following is my `VagrantFile`

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

I can see the following when I do `vagrant ssh`.

```
  System load:  0.07              Processes:             99
  Usage of /:   13.5% of 9.63GB   Users logged in:       0
  Memory usage: 12%               IP address for enp0s3: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%                IP address for enp0s8: 172.28.128.3
```

When I do the following `nc -vz 172.28.128.3 8500` on my host mac I get the error

`nc: connectx to 172.28.128.3 port 8500 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you can expose the running Consul agent UI in the box to the host.

- Configure running [service port to be forwarded to the host](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports).

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8500, host: 8500
end
```

The service would be available at `http://localhost:8500/ui`.

- Configure a [public network](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network).

> Tread with care as this exposes the entire box to the host.

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.17"
end
```

- Use [vagrant connect command](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/share/connect)

```
vagrant connect
```

The resulting Static IP can be used together with the service port.